# Is it a positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a p.s.d matrix $K$, is $2\operatorname{Diag}(K)-K$ a p.s.d matrix? Here, $\operatorname{Diag}(K)$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal is the diagonal of $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Define an $n\times n$ matrix $K$ by $K_{ij} = 1$ for every $1\leq i,j\leq n$. $K$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. However, $2I - K$ is not positive semi-definite.

Comment: Is $2Diag(K)-K$ diagonally dominant?

Comment: No! All diagonal entries are equal to 1; non-diagonal entries add up to $-(n-1)$ in every row and column. If it was diagonally dominant, it would be psd.

Comment: @Yury: Your $2I-K$ *is* positive semi-definite when $n=2$ :-D